# Hive concatenate column only if the next row has same value on another column

Tags: hive

in Hive I have a table like below

```
column1 column2 column3
    a   x       TT
    c   y       TT
    a   x2      TT
    a   x3      TT
    c   y4      TT
    c   y5      TT
    c   y6      TT
```

How could i convert into

```
column1 column2          column3
    a   x                TT
    c   y                TT
    a   x2 x3            TT
    c   y4 y5 y6         TT
```

Basically I want to concatenate `column2` value from the next row only if `column1` next row has same value

I tried dense_rank but not getting required result

Comment: this isnt possible. When you compare some row with next row, you need to have an order. In the DB, data can be stored in any order, and its possible all column1 =X be together and your result can be wrong. So, you need to decide what would be the order of comparison and then use listagg to concat column2.